# Does gRPC support TLS 1.3 under Android?

Tags: okhttp, grpc-java

In an Android App, using the latest release of `io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.32.1`, I cannot seem to make a TLS 1.3 connection to a server.  The definition of `ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS` is being referenced from okhttp-2.7.4, which does not include TLS 1.3.  I see that okhttp3 has the desired definition of `ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS`, but OKHttpChannelBuilder won't take that class reference.

Is there a way to create a gRPC `ManagedChannel` supporting TLS 1.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved> As of io.grpc version 1.43.2, there is a different method for building the Channel, with the TLS version and cipher suites as parameters.  Using this, I was able to create a TLS 1.3 connection.

`((OkHttpChannelBuilder) channelBuilder).tlsConnectionSpec(tlsVersions, cipherSuites);`

Answer (score 3):

If you're not particular to Google’s implementation you can use Wire’s gRPC client. It'll do TLSv1.3 on devices that support it. Or use it with Conscrypt for TLSv1.3 on any device.

https://square.github.io/wire/

Comment: I hadn't even considered different client implementations. Thanks for pointing me to a workable option!